# Why do blocks create a retain cycle when referencing self?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have read many articles that talk about blocks creating a retain cycle.  But why would it make a retain cycle?  Wouldn't the block release the reference after it got run?

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5
                 animations:^{
            self.variable = somevalue;
}];
```

For example if the above were executed, the reference to self would be released right?

I already see that the above block creates two strong references.  One from the object to the block and the block to the object.
Can someone explain to me why the cycle doesn't break?  Shouldn't the cycle break after the code is run?

Comment: It's only a problem if `self` is also retaining the block.

Comment: FYI - Objective-C is case sensitive. Your question should also be (at least the code you post).

Answer (score 4):

If an object holds a block and the block holds the object then that's a cycle.

If someone else holds the block and the block holds the object then there's a cycle only if the object directly or indirectly holds whomever holds the block.

Blocks do not self destruct upon being run so the cycle will be broken only if the block is deallocated.

Comment: So based off your answer, uiview animateswithduration:animation: will not create a cycle since uiview is holding on to the block.

Comment: And if I use dispatch_async it would also not create a retain cycle...  Right?

Comment: Those should both be true, yes. Though often people prefer to keep a `weak` reference going into an asynchronous block of any variety so as not artificially to extend the lifetime of the relevant object. That's more of a `dispatch_async` comment than a `UIView +animateWithDuration:...` comment though — the completion part of the latter will occur later but no later than the fixed time you've set for the animation, which is usually tiny.